# Add HTML code inside an iframe generated from Google Docs

Tags: html, iframe

I have a Google Docs documented that I publish using the share feature as an iframe snippet. On my website I then want to [translate this document using a Weglot plugin](https://developers.weglot.com/javascript/translate-iframe) that requires to inject a code snippet inside the iframe generated from Google Docs.

Any hack to do this with an iframe that I don't have control over?

Comment: for security reasons, you can do some very limited things to iframes, but not very much, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/251420/. MDN has some useful content about iframe security in the last paragraph of this section - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#scripting